# Not able to play video using primefaces media in primefaces version 6.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
public StreamedContent getVideoFile() {

    HttpSessionUtil<byte[]> sessionUtil =  new HttpSessionUtil<byte[]>();
    byte[] videoFile = sessionUtil.getFromSessionMap("video");
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {

        videoFile = convertDefaultVideoToBytes(videoFile);
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new 
                ByteArrayInputStream(videoFile), "video/mp4");
    }

    if(videoFile != null && videoFile.length > 0){
        videoFile = new DefaultStreamedContent(new 
        ByteArrayInputStream(videoFile), "video/mp4");

    }else{

        videoFile = convertDefaultVideoToBytes(videoFile);
        videoFile = new DefaultStreamedContent(new 
        ByteArrayInputStream(videoFile), "video/mp4");

    }
    return videoFile;
}
```

xhtml code:

```
    <p:media value="#{vesumeBean.videoFile}" width="100%" height="400" 
                                player="quicktime">
        <f:param name="autoPlay" value="true" />
    </p:media>
```

The ManagedBean is javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
The final byte[] length of video comes around 480835

The objective is the video should start playing after the screen is loaded.
Not able to play video using p:media.

- Tech stack used : JSF/Primefaces 6.0/Wildfly10.1.0 Final.  Problem:
- p:media doesnot load/play the video file
- Error:[org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler] : 
        Error in streaming dynamic resource. null

The video should get loaded from the specified path and start playing.

FacesContext.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE this block is executed twice and third time it comes to the else part

It works in Firefox perfectly. Any help related to this is highly appreciated.

Comment: So it worked in PF 5.3?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, Right now not feasible to try with 5.3  :) . I dont know how it works in firefox. Is there any browser compatibility factor in <p:media which I am missing

Comment: Not even q quick trying for one page? Ok... but you explicitly mentioned 6.0 in the title, suggesting with that that it worked before. And no there is, afaik, not a browser compatibility factor. Try with IE10? IE running in 'compatibility mode'? Lots of basic IE things to **try**

Comment: Currently the product is compatible only with Chrome,Safari and Firefox..So the IE also gets ruled out..Sorry for the same. :(

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, I tried in IE also.But it does not play. I placed a video (480KB) in local drive and tried. It plays only in firefox as stated above. Chrome and IE no. I chaged the content-type to video/mpeg. In chrome the file gets downloaded automatically as dynamiccontent.properties. Do I need to specify the mime-type in web.xml . Any suggestions/advice highly appreciated.

Comment: I could not make it work so shifted to <iframe with the servlet concept and it works ...